# Warum zwiegespalten, Zwiegespräch, Zwieback, Zwietracht, aber Zweikampf, Zweirad?

Tags: etymology

Bei Wörter mit einer Herkunft von zwei etwas gibt es manchmal der Form mit *zwie-*:

Zwiegespräch, Zwieback, Zwietracht

und manchmal mit *zwei-*:

Zweikampf, Zweirad

Und es gibt sowohl *zweigespalten* als *zwiegespalten*, wobei früher *zweigespalten* dominant war, aber heute *zwiegespalten*:

[image: google ngram Statistik zwiegespalten / zweigespalten]
*Quelle: [Google Ngram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSU7V.png)*

Warum habe manche Wörter zwie-, manche Wörter zwei-, und hat es bei *zwiegespalten* einen Wechsel gegeben?  Ich meine, dass es in bestimmte Dialekte einen Wechsel gibt zwischen den Läuten /aɪ/ und /ɪ/, allerdings sagen wir niemals *zwie* statt *zwei* (man kann *zwo* sagen, aber mit sind keine Wortbildungen mit *zwo* bekannt, jedenfalls nicht als Schriftsprache).

Comment: Aber wir sagen 'zwo'.

Comment: Auch: *Zwiegespräch*, *Zwieback*.

Comment: Beantwortet die Etymologie von _zwie-_ https://www.dwds.de/wb/zwie- deine Frage? Falls nein, was meinst du mit "warum"?

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Vielleicht; ich glaube, ich muss das vielleicht dreimal lesen. Also bei älteren Bildungen haben wir "zwie-", bei neueren "zwei-"?  Allerdings erklärt das nicht der Wechsel bei *zwiegespalten*.

Comment: Danke für dir Präzisierung! Ich würde vermuten, dass _zwiegespalten_ sich nachträglich an _zwiespältig_ anlehnt. Aber das kann ich nicht belegen.

Comment: Wenn ich mir die Google-Treffer zu "zweigespalten" aus dem 19. Jahrhundert ansehe, scheint dort biologische oder anatomische Fachliteratur vorzuherrschen - dort kann nur "zweigespalten" zutreffend sein (das Blatt ist zweigespalten, nicht zwiegespalten).  Der Befund kann also schlicht korpusspezifisch sein.

Comment: Siehe auch Zwilling, Zwille, Zwiebel usw.

Answer (score 4):

Siehe die Wörterbücher von Kluge oder Wolfgang Pfeifer zur Lautgeschichte (DWDS.de [[1](https://dwds.de/wb/zwei)])

Der reguläre Ausgang des Zahlwortes wäre *zwo*.  *Zwei* entstand vermutlich durch Assimilation in der Aufzählung *eins, zwei, drei* [Kluge]. Die Wurzel lässt sich gewisser Maßen bis in der Vorzeit zurückverfolgen. Indogermanisten der letzten 150 Jahre rekonstruieren *dwo- (bzw. *du̯ō(u) [Pfeifer]): vgl. Englisch *two*, latein *duo*, etc.

Daneben werden *Kompositionsformen*  ****dwei-*** und ****dwi-*** geführt: vgl. englisch *twilight* "Zwielicht, Dämmerung", Latein *di, dui-*, *bis ~ bi-*, daher bspw. *biscuit* "Weichkeks" wie *Zwieback*; demnach ebenso ***bicycle***.

Daraus lässt sich schlussfolgern, das *Zweirad* muss eine neuere Wortschöpfung sein, sowie die Erfindung des Drahtesels relativ jung ist.

---

Allerdings ist schon im Mittelniederdeutschen Varianz mitsamt *twē, twei, twī* für das Zahlwort nachweisbar, das nach Umlautung (ca. 13. - 15. Jh.) zwar unserer *Zwei* entsprechen dürfte (Hörprobe bei Fettes Brot, *Nordisch by Nature*).

Somit ist *Zweifel* angezeigt: vgl. französisch *doubt, dubios*, griechisch *diploid*, gothisch *tweifels*, laut Pfeifer auf **du̯ei-* zurückzuführen, sowie bis zum Neuhochdeutschen *zwīfel* steht, niederdeutsch *twīvel*.

Für den Diphtong *-ei-* ist augenscheinlich der Akzentsitz auf der ersten Silbe verantwortlich, der für Simplexe im deutschen typisch ist, sowie der Suffix unbetont ist. Da *ein-fäl-tig*, usw. jedoch nicht ohne weiteres mit *Faltung* erklärt werden können (s. Meinungen von Latin.SE bzgl. *replicare* "reply") ist diese Formation sowieso fragwürdig.

---

Übrigens scheint es auch Verwechslung mit *dwis- zu geben, vgl. *zer-*, lateinisch *dis-*; zudem *Zwist* "Disput", *twist* "zerreißen". Obgleich *wi- wenn überhaupt nur als spätere Ableitung behandelt wird, vgl. *wider*, *wieder*, *Widerstreit, Wiederwort*, insb. Sanskrit *vi-*, so besteht über die Verhältnisse letztendlich doch noch Unklarheit.

Comment: Sehr strukturierter und verständlicher Beitrag! +1

Answer (score 4):

1. Der Wechsel /i/ – /aɪ/ hat nichts mit der [neuhochdeutschen Diphthongierung](https://www.adfontes.uzh.ch/tutorium/die-deutsche-sprache-in-den-quellen/neuere-sprachentwicklungen/die-fruehneuhochdeutsche-diphthongierung/) zu tun, da das Ahd. auch schon die Form *zwei* hatte (im Nom. Akk. Neut. sowie im Gen. und Dat. aller Genera, [BMZ](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/BMZ?lemid=Z01134)). Auch die ältere Genusdifferenzierung (in Dialekten bis heute erhalten, s. [diesen Beitrag](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/70386/35111)) m. *zwēne*, f. *zwā, zwō*, n. *zwei* hat damit nichts zu tun.

2. Die Form *zwi-* tritt seit ahd. Zeit in Komposita auf: ahd. *zwifalt* "doppelt", *zwibar* "Zuber" (wg. der zwei Griffe); s. [Köbler](http://www.koeblergerhard.de/ahd/5A/ahd_z.html).

3. *Zwiegespalten* ist an sich ein sehr junges Wort; siehe die Wortverlaufskurven bei [*zwiegespalten*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zwiegespalten), [*zwiespältig*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zwiesp%C3%A4ltig), [*Zwiespalt*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Zwiespalt).

4. Produktiv ist wahrscheinlich nur noch *zwei-*; das junge *zwiegespalten* ist offensichtlich in Analogie zu älterem *zwiespältig* gebildet.

5. Während die Komposita mit *zwei-* eher wörtlich verstanden werden, haben die mit *zwie-* tendentiell übertragene Bedeutung (oder die Bedeutung ist ganz verblaßt). Wenn es um den inneren Konflikt geht, würde ich daher *zwiegespalten* erwarten; die (normalerweise älteren) Belege mit *zweigespalten* sind aber wörtlich gemeint: *Die Menschen auf der Welt sind leider zweigespalten, die Frommen ohn' Vernunft, Vernünf'tge ohne Glauben* ([Quelle](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Uebersicht_der_Literaturgeschichte_der_A/-VxDAAAAcAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&dq=%22Die+Menschen+auf+der+Welt+sind+leider+zweigespalten%22&pg=PA915&printsec=frontcover)).

6. *Zwie-* als gebundene Einheit hat eigene Wörterbucheinträge, siehe z.B. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zwie-), [DWB](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=Z13244).

Kurzzusammenfassung: Konkurrenz der alten gebundenen Form *zwie-* mit dem freien *zwei* und Differenzierung des Gebrauchs.